# Как задать в коде ограничение по использованию оперативной памяти?

Tags: java, память

В интернете смог найти только ограничение аргументами при запуске из командной строки.

Можно ли задать ограничение внутри кода, во время выполнения?

Answer (score 3):

Во время выполнения программы нет возможности регулировать параметры `-Xmx` и `-Xms`. Их можно задать только перед началом работы.

Но возникает вопрос: а для чего это необходимо? Вы можете подобрать подходящие параметры перед стартом программы. Например, выделить приложению максимально доступный объем памяти.

Либо как вариант: запускать во время выполнения новый процесс и задавать новые параметры JVM.

Comment: то есть, если я запишу это в стартер - Main (String...args), то это то же самое, что задам аргументы в командной строке? Ограничение будет работать?

Comment: Нет, аргументы в args - это аргументы запускаемого приложения, а не виртуальной машины. Пример запуска нового процесса: `java <параметры JVM> -jar app.jar`